# PostGIS St_snapToGrid doesn't work on Z-value

Tags: postgis, postgresql

As the title says, it seems `ST_SnapToGrid` doesn't work on Z-values.

Example:

```
SELECT
id, ST_AsText(ST_Snaptogrid(ST_Transform(pos,2056),0.01)) as pos,
FROM tablename LIMIT 2;
```

Give me 2 WKT geometry as expected, X,Y are rounded, but Z-value comes with it's 11 or 12 decimals.

Here's my PostGIS version as given by `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`:

```
"POSTGIS="2.2.1 r14555" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" SFCGAL="1.2.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" TOPOLOGY RASTER"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variant of ST_SnapToGrid that you are using doesn't touch z-geometry. You can see this in the documentation: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html
Not sure if this is intentional but I think it is because the earlier versions of postgis didn't support it and they didn't want to suddenly change the behaviour in a new version.

Try to use the 4'th variant (from the doc) that defines a z and m spacing as well:

```
SELECT
ST_AsText(ST_Snaptogrid(
    ST_MakePoint(1.1,1.1,2.5)
    ,ST_MakePoint(0,0,0)
    ,1,1,1,1)) as pos
```